# How to include sonar-scanner.jar file through docker compose?

Tags: docker-compose, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarscanner, sonar-scanner-cli

I have started learning sonarqube and run sonar-scanner to analyse the code.

I have setup sonarqube on MAC with the help of below **docker-compose** file, with command `docker-compose up -d`

```
version: "3"
services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    hostname: sonarqube
    container_name: sonarqube
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    hostname: postgresql
    container_name: postgresql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
      POSTGRES_DB: sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

I have launched url `http://localhost:9000` and created project manually and generated key (for simple python script in a folder), to see how it executes and analyses the report.

Executed scanner command from cli :

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=<ProjectKey> \
  -Dsonar.sources=. \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.token=<GeneratedToken> -X
```

**Error :**

```
17:32:39.993 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /Users/<username>/Downloads/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006-macosx/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
17:32:40.036 INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
17:32:40.071 INFO: SonarScanner 5.0.1.3006
17:32:40.072 INFO: Java 17.0.7 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
17:32:40.072 INFO: Mac OS X 13.5.2 x86_64
17:32:40.286 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
17:32:40.286 DEBUG: keyStore type is : pkcs12
17:32:40.287 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
17:32:40.287 DEBUG: init keystore
17:32:40.287 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
17:32:40.473 DEBUG: Create: /Users/<username>/.sonar/cache
17:32:40.474 INFO: User cache: /Users/<username>/.sonar/cache
17:32:40.474 DEBUG: Create: /Users/<username>/.sonar/cache/_tmp
17:32:40.478 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
17:32:40.486 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
17:32:40.486 DEBUG: Download: http://localhost:9000/batch/index
17:37:40.613 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:37:40.618 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
17:37:40.618 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:37:40.625 INFO: Total time: 5:00.668s
17:37:40.692 INFO: Final Memory: 5M/54M
17:37:40.692 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:37:40.693 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:286)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$AbstractSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:389)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$UnknownLengthSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:529)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.java:286)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.select(RealBufferedSource.java:100)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:467)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:181)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:100)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.endRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    ... 19 more
```

From above error, I noticed that it has stuck at the point `Download: http://localhost:9000/batch/index` , when I browsed this url, noticed that it's trying to find `scanner.jar` file i.e., `sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-10.2.0.77647-all.jar|da07b1882a8a64a25af0bd91f2f62309`

Do I need to point this scanner.jar externally ? Definitely, this scanner.jar is missing in my configuration, Can you please help me here ? I really need your assistance. Am I missing anything here ?
Any helps here is greatly appreciated.